# Flutter valores de las propiedades de un Map tratados todos como string

Tags: lista, flutter, dart, map

Tengo una lista de esta forma `a = [{'uno': 'one', 'dos': null, 'tres':[{'cuatro':'four'}]}]`

Lo envio a una funcion para usarlo en un post request la cual en el body debe de recibir un Map, entonces lo k hice fue esto `a[0]`, el problema es que me sale este error `The getter 'length' was called on null`

Me pongo a revisar y me trata todos los valores de las propiedades como si fueran Strings, incluso la lista anidada `'tres':[{'cuatro':'four'}]`, he tratado de enviar el post de esta forma `http.post(url, body: (recurrencia[0] as Map))` pero no ha servido siempre me da el mismo error, incluso si en el body pongo las propiedades a mano `body: {'nueva propiedad': a[0]['tres']}`, como se debe accionar para solucionar este problema?. Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Code:

```
void _ordersGet() async {         
    await http.get(url).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        orders = jsonDecode(value.body);
      }
}
```

orders es enviado a un nuevo widget: `orderList(orders)`

orderList es un listView

```
ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      primary: false,
      itemCount: orders.length,
      itemBuilder: (orders, index) {
        return return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[              
          Text(orders[index]['facts']),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text('Cantidad : '),
          Text(orders[index]['ITEMS'][0]['jeans']),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () => _reorderData(context, orders[index]),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.replay_outlined,
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              )),
        ],
      ),
        );
      },
    );
```

_reorderData es una funcion que realiza un get request y la data es enviada a ReorderModal

ReorderModal solo muestra la informacion de la data y tiene un boton

```
void _reorderData(BuildContext ctx, order) async {
    var data;
    var url = 'serverAddress/${order['facts']}';
   
    await http.get(url).then((value) {
      data = jsonDecode(value.body);
      data[0]['CORPORATION'] = order['corporation'];

      showModalBottomSheet(
          context: ctx,
          builder: (_) {
            return ReorderModal(data);
          });
    }).catchError((onError) {});
  }

class ReorderModal extends StatelessWidget {
  final List data;
  ReorderModal(this.data);
  
  void orderSend(Map orderInfo) async {        
    var url = 'serverAddress';

    await http.post(url, body: orderInfo).then((value) {

      print(jsonDecode(value.body));

    }).catchError((onError) {
      
      print(onError);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: Column(
              children: [Text(
                    data[0]['ITEMS']['DESCRIPCION']                           
                  ),                        
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              orderSend(data[0]);
              //print(data);
            },
            child: Text('ONE Click'))
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Cuando presiono el boton ONE Click, se ejecuta la funcion orderSend, la cual recibe un map y me sale esto:
I/flutter ( 9714): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 9714): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 9714): Tried calling: length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando hagas un post con cuerpo `JSON` necesitas hacer un `jsonEncode`.

```dart
http.post(
    'url',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'title': title,
    }),
```

Te dejo este link de referencia: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data

Comment: Tengo otro post y no tengo que utilizar el json mas o menos es de esta forma ``Map a = {'uno':'one', 'dos':'two'}, http.post(url, a), pero vere si tu propuesta me ayuda a resolver este tema, muchas gracias por la rapida respuesta

Comment: no funciono nada >.<, desde mi pto de vista creo que el tema esta en la variable, pero no encuentro la forma de accionar T_T, para una mejor explicacion tengo un objeto el cual tiene una propiedad con valor null y me da este error The getter 'length' was called on null, pero los objetos pueden tener valores null y si fuera todo un String no podria hacer esto objecto['propiedad']

Comment: no entendí bien, si tu map es null entonces no podrás acceder a los objetos dentro

Comment: mi map esta asi ``a = [{'uno': 'one', 'dos': null, 'tres':[{'cuatro':'four'}]}]``, cuando lo envio por el post me dice que ``The getter 'length' was called on null``, incluso esta propiedad ``'tres':[{'cuatro':'four'}]`` cuando la llamo de esta forma a['tres'] si le pongo un punto delante del ``]`` VS code me da una serie de opciones que deberian ser para una lista y no lo hace, solo me salen 4 opciones: hashcode, runtimeType, toString() y noSuchMethod(). VS code no cree que sea una variable tipo Map, incluso cuando la funcion la tengo de esta forma nombreFuncion(Map variable)

Comment: Es que necesitas decirle que tipo es (a['tres'] as List)

Comment: Eso lo se, incluso si le digo a la funcion k recibe: funcionPrueba(Map variable) se supone k debe ser un map lo que recibe y si no, se cae todo y aun asi me da el error The getter 'length' was called on null cuando hago el post, ese error me sale por que hay pripiedades cuyos valores son null, agrego un poco mas de codigo

Comment: agrega más detalle a tu pregunta, que código usas, cual es el resultado, en que línea marca el error, etc.

Comment: Buenas, ya resolvi el tema, hice exactamente lo que propusiste en tu respuesta. No queria hacerlo asi y no entiendo por que de la forma que estaba haciendolo no se podia, pero lo importante fue que ya pude hacer el post y se guardo la info. Muchas gracias por tu amabilidad

Comment: No hay de que, si quieres contenido flutter avanzado te recomiendo mi canal : youtube.com/diegoveloper

Comment: llevo varios dias suscrito xD... ahora inicio con los videos, muchas gracias nuevamente